# Why is psxdll.dll on my system?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dll

I'm aware that `psxdll.dll` is a component of Windows Services for UNIX.  However, this was never installed on my system.  So, I'm trying to figure out what other program(s) might have installed the DLL and/or which programs may be using it.

Are there any "likely suspects"?

Related:  [How can I find out what program installed or is using a specific DLL file?](https://superuser.com/questions/370796/how-can-i-find-out-what-program-installed-or-is-using-a-specific-dll-file)

Comment: Check the dll creation date, see if it matches up with any software installation dates.

Comment: This tool may also help if you have suspect programs...http://mark0.net/soft-bdllscan-e.html